# HTML5 Video Not Working, IE11

Tags: javascript, html5-video, internet-explorer-11

I am in Windows Server 2012. I uploaded a site that works fine in my laptop, but has problems when I test it on the server's IE 11.0.9600.16384.

I have this code to insert html5 videos in the site

```
document.getElementById("videogal").innerHTML=' ';

elemv.src=mplv[0];

document.getElementById("videogal").appendChild(elemv);
```

`videogal` is a `div`

`elemv` is a global `var`:

```
 var elemv = document.createElement("video");
```

`mplv` is an array that contains literals, such as `"myFolder/myvideo.mp4"`.

As I said, it works fine in my laptop, but *not* in server's IE. IE's console says `Not Implemented` and marks this line `elemv.src=mplv[0];`

I dont know how to handle that. I alert the `mplv[0]` and has the proper value.

*Most important*: will this bug appear in client's browsers also? Or is just locally on server. I connect to the server as Admin and have turned off all the security restrictions of the IE.

Comment: Do you have Desktop Experience installed?

Comment: @misterben No. Is that a program?

Comment: It's a Windows "feature". I haven't used Server 2012 but with Server 2008 you don't get HTML5 video without it, and I dare say it's the same. See e.g. http://yellowduckguy.wordpress.com/2012/12/21/windows-server-2012-how-to-add-desktop-experience-feature/

Comment: @misterben Interesting. I will give it a try. But, let me ask you, what does this has to do with the IE11? Is it necessary to make the video work in the client's browser?

Comment: As the name suggests, it adds "desktop" functionality (such as the capability to play video in IE) that's left out of a "server" OS by default. It has no impact on any other machine.

Comment: @misterben So, its not necessary for the client's browser to display an html5 video? And has to do with IE only, right? Because I can see the vidoe in server's Chrome...

Comment: This comment thread is getting a bit long. I've wrapped this up into an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows Server does not by default include certain "desktop" functionality, which includes the ability to play HTML5 video in Internet Explorer. Typically you wouldn't want users using server resources to play video. [The *"Desktop Experience"* feature can be installed](http://yellowduckguy.wordpress.com/2012/12/21/windows-server-2012-how-to-add-desktop-experience-feature/) to add that functionality.

Installing this has no bearing on another machine's ability to play video served from this server. Other browsers (e.g. Chrome) running on the server have their own capability to play video and are unaffected by this feature being installed or not.

Comment: Nice anser. Thanks for your time and patience

Comment: For Windows Server 2008 R2, you might also need to download a fix from Microsoft http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2483177 after Desktop Experience is installed.